# Print pdf file with Zebra Printer using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, zebra-printers

I'm trying to develop an android app to print a pdf file with my zebra printer, but i'm not being able to.
I'm using Link-OS SDK and Xamarin forms.

I've tried using `.SendFileContents` and `.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdf)` but it just prints a bunch of ASCII characters.

Link-OS docs: https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/xamarin/content/index.html

Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.zebra.com/blog/printing-pdfs-android-link-os-printers

Comment: I need a solution for c#

Comment: Translating Java to C# should not be difficult.  The article walks you through all of the necessary API calls needed to print

Comment: My file is already located in my phone, so I just give the path like this: `printer.SendFileContents(path + "/dummy.pdf");` but it still doesnt print the pdf's content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past.
my request was to print a PDF via bluetooth to a ZEBRA printer.

I honestly tell you that in the end I didn't implement the issue, for a whole series of technical issues.

I finally settled on this solution:

1. open the PDF using a generic PDF viewer
2. print through this application (you will still need to install some useful drivers for the matter)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to need to encapsulate the file contents into ZPL (Zebra Print Language). These printers speak their own native language and are not like a regular Laser/Ink Jet printers. The commands are pretty simple and typically layout text fields and barcode fields in dot coordinates. You're gonna have a little heavy lifting but not too much!
Check this out for more details on ZPL [ZPL Support Page](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/ZPL-Command-Information-and-DetailsV2?language=en_US)